# Ubuntu 20.04 All files transfered to shared folder are locked with user = nobody and group = none

Tags: networking, samba, sharing

I have a very simple, purely Ubuntu 22.04 network - no mixed OS - No Windows. 2 identical laptops, Laptop A has a shared folder which I access from Laptop B. The username and password on both machines are identical.

Even though I am not using Windows anywhere, Ubuntu insisted on installing Samba in order to share my folder.

I can transfer files from B to A and see all the files in the shared folder on A from either laptop - great !

The problem I have is that if I transfer any files from B to A, or Edit files in the shared folder on A - via Laptop B all files display a red padlock when viewing them on Laptop A. They all show permissions as owner = nobody, group = none when examined on A. If I try to view permissions using Laptop B it says permissions could not be determined.

So I cannot access any files on A that were transferred from, edited from or created from B. On B I can access the shared folder perfectly and edit files, but on A, the machine where the shared folder actually exists, I can see them all, with a padlock and not edit them.

If I create the files on A I can edit from either machine but as soon as i edit on B they are locked on A

I would like all files in the shared folder to be fully accessible from both machines, and ideally a permanent solution ie not a command I need to run every time a new file is added.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

Try running the chmod command.

```
 sudo chmod -Rf 777 ~/Shared Folder
```

Edited ==========================

The most common types of permits are the following:

666 ( RW / RW / RW) - Allows all users to read and write a file.

777 ( RWX / RWX /RWX) - Allows all users to read, write, and execute a file.

755 (RWX / RW / RW) - Allows the file owner to read, write, and execute a file, while others can only read and write a file.

644 (RW / R / R) -  Allows the owner to read and write a file, while others can only read.

700 (RWX /---) - It allows the owner to read, write and execute a file, while others do not have any access.

Comment: Will that make changes permanently or will I need to run it every time I add new file. I would really like a permanent solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, whilst this 'resets' the contents so it can be accessed, as soon as a file is modified and saved on the remote laptop (B in my post) the file permissions revert. So I would have to check every time a file was accessed and run the command again

Comment: So, you may have Samba configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution (maybe a workaround) at last!

chmod and chown only allowed access until a file was edited or a new file was transferred - it did not persist and I would have had to keep running it.

Instead -

I edited the /etc/samba/smb.conf file on the 'server' machine, the one that physically has the shared folder.

First I changed the line (100 on my installation) that says 'map to guest = bad user' to 'map to guest = never'.

I was then only ever able to log in as 'Anonymous' or in other words 'Guest'. This led me to the realisation that Samba was not actually accepting my Login credentials and always logging me in as guest, resulting in the nobody / none properties on files I created or edited. More annoyingly there was no warning or error message, I could type in anything and simply be logged in as Guest without notification.

Then I found a reference to a line saying that there was a default setting defined by the line 'guest account = nobody' but this line did not appear in my smb.conf. So I added it at the end of the [global] section of smb.conf (line 34 on my installation) but changed it to 'guest account = John'. John being my user name on both laptops (it's not really, just an example). I have the same user name, password and groups on each machine.

Now I can only access the share as Anonymous (Guest) but it identifies me as John. So now I can create, read, edit, delete files in the shared folder from  either machine. Properties on the central laptop show the correct permissions, but when viewed via satellite laptop I get a message that the permissions cannot be determined - not a major problem for me.

Now for the security conscious, this may not be an ideal fix, but for me accessing the files over my network as Guest (Anonymous) is not a problem. I have to log in to each machine anyway. It is more important for me to be able to have access and full control of the shared folder and its contents from any machine, irrespective of where they were created or transferred from.

I will need to investigate why Samba does not recognise my credentials but I am up and running and have full access to my files from all machines I log in to. I left the 'map to guest = bad user' line in to remind me, and to restrict me to only logging in as Anonymous.

Comment: No where in any of your posts did you mention adding your login user name to the samba password database:  `sudo smbpasswd -a your-login-user-name` . Did I miss something?

Comment: @Morbius1 - I did not. I am very new to Ubuntu 20.04 and have never used Samba before. I simply followed the instructions when I tried to share a folder and Ubuntu informed me it was installing Samba. I will investigate this commant to see how to use it - thankyou